# LSOpenURLsWithRole() errors when in a tmux session

Tags: python, macos, terminal, tmux, simplehttpserver

`LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -600 for the URL http://localhost:9000/.`

This is the error I get when I try to launch my `SimpleHTTPServer` while in a `tmux` session. I'm a front-end web developer and I spend most of my time working with a `SimpleHTTPServer`, rather than `Apache`. The issue is that it errors out at the `open` command, because I have the habit of opening files and directories from the terminal directly (`open dirname/`, or `open .`) , and when i use this in `tmux` it gives me the same error.
I want to mention that I'm on a Macbook Air, running OSX 10.9 Mavericks.

This is the code of the function I use in my terminal to start the server:

```
# Start an HTTP server from a directory, optionally specifying the port
function server() {
    local port="${1:-8000}"
    open "http://localhost:${port}/"
    # Set the default Content-Type to `text/plain` instead of `application/octet-stream`
    # And serve everything as UTF-8 (although not technically correct, this doesn’t break anything for binary files)
    python -c $'import SimpleHTTPServer;\nmap = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map;\nmap[""] = "text/plain";\nfor key, value in map.items():\n\tmap[key] = value + ";charset=UTF-8";\nSimpleHTTPServer.test();' "$port" 
}
```

## Edit

The issue doesn't appear anymore so I have 3 possible solutions for this:

Highly unlikely:

- changing from Python3 to Python 2.7.5 (OS X Default)

Most likely:

- Apple released an update to Mavericks that fixes this issue
- installing Command-Line tools in order to use Homebrew to build & install the latest version of VIM

Comment: Was your `tmux` session started from an ssh connection, or at least not from the Mac UI? This causes `open` to not be able to connect to the window server which might trigger the error.

Comment: @robertklep No, it wasn't. It was a local session that I started on my machine. I tried that night to start multiple sessions, in different ways, after reboots, etc. , but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: I see this on Yosemite and nodeJs with tmux

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the same case for you, since you mentioned you restarted a few times ...

However for me, I noticed that I had stray 2 tmux sessions after an iterm failure, which I had forgotten about. They were running a bunch of services started by grunt, so i'm assuming that one of these services was conflicting when trying to start again. Killing them made the bug not occur anymore and I was able to run my node app in tmux.

Comment: the issue dissappeared at one point. I see that you're also reporting it on Yosemite w/ NodeJS+tmux, but I wonder if you are using the SimpleHTTPServer from python, or are you using a NodeJS webserver, like the generated by the http module or by expressJS.  Let me know what's your case, maybe I can test on my machine.

Comment: not using python, using expressJs
I actually get this a lot now with Yosemite that tends to close all my applications at random moments. Then I have to attach to the tmux session or kill all sessions, and the problem goes away.

Comment: That's weird, maybe you could try installing [Onyx for Yosemite](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11582/onyx) -- a cleanup tool that I use very often, and run it's scripts, repair disk/directory permissions, reset other home dir permissions and other stuff and throw in a restart. Let me knof how it went.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Cosmin said, check if there is another tmux running, kill all tmux.

Then open a new tmux, it will work like before.